# C# Entity framework. Order all hierarchical nodes according to "Name" column

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, treeview

I have an entity framework model with a hierarchical setup by relationships. Table1 -> Table2 -> Table3 -> Table4 -> Table 5. I have set up a treeview with hierarchical template in my WPF application that's source is binded to the Entity framework local data.

My entities' classes are all made of observable collections. Each of these classes inherit a base class, which has ID and Name.

I have managed to get the top level parent to sort, but I am unable to get any of the child nodes and their child nodes etc to sort:

```
 TreeSetup.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

I have also tried to use OrderBy in my entity framework context. But the  same result followed. 
Does anyone have a solution that will order all elements of my treeview, and also all future nodes that are added.

Here is a converter I am using, which works only once. And does not update my tree as changes are made. I am assuming it is because I am binding it to the "view property and not the original context anymore.

```
  public class SortNodesAlphabetically : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        if(value is ObservableCollection<tblProject>)
        {
        ObservableCollection<tblProject> view = (ObservableCollection<tblProject>) value;
         return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblLine>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblLine> view = (ObservableCollection<tblLine>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblGroup>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblGroup> view = (ObservableCollection<tblGroup>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblStation>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblStation> view = (ObservableCollection<tblStation>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblDevice>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblDevice> view = (ObservableCollection<tblDevice>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblSubDevice>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblSubDevice> view = (ObservableCollection<tblSubDevice>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        if (value is ObservableCollection<tblSubSubDevice>)
        {
            ObservableCollection<tblSubSubDevice> view = (ObservableCollection<tblSubSubDevice>)value;
            return view.OrderBy(o => o.Name); ;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I followed an answer from a similar post. Answered by IVerzin How to sort TreeView items using SortDescriptions in Xaml?

However, new objects in my context are still not sorted

Comment: Does all table1,2.... e.t.c are of Same ViewModel type while being bound to TreeView?

Comment: @user1672994 I bind directly to my context. So I use my base table like a viewmodel. which all of the tables implement (However they are not all the same.)

Comment: Managed to get a converter working, however, it seems to remove the effects of my PropertyChanged event. (Treeview stops showing new nodes)